# Loading Extjs grid from an XML string instead of file

Tags: xml, extjs

I've been able to get ExtJS grids to create from external XML files. I usually define stores as follows:

```
var store = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'PersonModel',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'MyXML.xml',
        reader: {
            type  : 'xml',
            record: 'Person'
        }
    }
});
```

I have an XML fragment stored in one of the fields, so let's just say I have it in a local variable. How can I implement the store to read from a variable/string and not from a file? Thanks.

Comment: by variable/string you mean database or local storage (array) ?

Comment: Found a few helpful postings online. The issue is they all seem to work in v2/3 and the code doesn't work in v4...

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?96757-How-manually-load-XML-to-Ext.Data.Store&p=457158&viewfull=1#post457158

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it to work. The trick was to define a memory type proxy and then pass a parsed xml object to it.

```
var xmlstr =    "<personRecord>" +
                    "<Person>" +
                        "<firstName>Stan</firstName>" +
                        "<lastName>C</lastName>" +
                    "</Person>" +
                    "<Person>" +
                        "<firstName>Stanley</firstName>" +
                        "<lastName>D</lastName>" +
                    "</Person>" +
                "</personRecord>";


var doc;
if (window.ActiveXObject) {         //IE
    var doc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    doc.async = "false";
    doc.loadXML(xmlstr);
} else {                             //Mozilla
    var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlstr, "text/xml");
}


var memstore = new Ext.data.Store({
    autoLoad: true,
    model: 'Person',
    data : doc,
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            record: 'Person'
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work when I dropped the data: doc declaration inside the proxy.
proxy:
{
    data: doc
    type: 'memory'
etc etc

EW

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this might work (admittedly I haven't tried it):

```
var data = "<user><name>Joe Bob</name></user>";
var store = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'PersonModel',
    data: data,
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type  : 'xml',
            record: 'Person'
        }
    }
});
```

You may also want to add `autoLoad: true` in the store's options so you don't have to call `store.load();`

Edit:
You may also want to consider changing the data a bit so it can be used by the array reader: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.data.reader.Array

Answer (score 0):

//this is the model we will be using in the store

```
Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'id',    type: 'int'},
        {name: 'name',  type: 'string'},
        {name: 'phone', type: 'string', mapping: 'phoneNumber'}
    ]
});
```

//this data does not line up to our model fields - the phone field is called phoneNumber

```
var data = {
    users: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Ed Spencer',
            phoneNumber: '555 1234'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Abe Elias',
            phoneNumber: '666 1234'
        }
    ]
};
```

//note how we set the 'root' in the reader to match the data structure above

```
var store = new Ext.data.Store({
    autoLoad: true,
    model: 'User',
    data : data,
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'users'
        }
    }
});
```

Refrence: 
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.data.proxy.Memory

Comment: Thanks, It is close to what I am looking for, but this is json, not xml. It does look like MemoryProxy is the way to go but I need to pass a string to it containing fragment of an XML file.

Comment: you just change your proxy to xml reader reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            root: 'users'
        }

Answer (score 0):

You can load store with local variable using
    store.loadData(xmlVar);